# mouseover, click etc .. wont work on subsequent pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a php file called main.php Inside of main i have a div defined that contains and image of a user profile. main is pretty much a top of page menu which gets included in other php files. There is also another div ( mmberNav ) in main that hides on the left side of the page.

The profile picture div has an id of 'menuAvatar'

so in essence I have

inside index.php I have

```
.
.
include(main.php)
.
.
.
```

My ajax is pretty straight for testing ..

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#menuAvatar').on( 'mouseover',  function() {
         $('#memberNav').css( 'left', '0');
      });
   bla
   bla 
   .
   .
```

In the above code when I hover of the the profile picture, the div ( memberNav ) which is hidden then appears. This works as expected on index.php

However, if i load the page members.php which has ..
include(main.php)
to show the top menu, the hover no longer works.

I have tried changing the div id of menuAvatar to a class instead of id but it still fails to respond to a mouseover or click.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: that is not ajax, that is jquery and what you are doing can be done with :hover in straight css.

Answer (score 0):

Does memberNav have an absolute position?

```
$(function() {
    $('#menuAvatar').hover(function() {
        $('#memberNav').css({'position':'absolute', 'left':'0'})
    })
});
```

Elements with `top` `left` `right` or `bottom` properties need to be absolutely positioned. If you aren't open to that you could try `margin-left` instead.